# if elseif else on ng-template and ng-container

Tags: angular, discrete-mathematics

I have declared 2 variables and they are changing depending the user logged.

```
public allowed: Boolean;
public myProfile: Boolean;
```

The logic to show one `div` or another `div` or both o no one

```
allowed === true && myProfile === true SHOW BOTH
allowed === false && myProfile === true SHOW RESET
allowed === true && myProfile === false SHOW RESTART
allowed === false &6 myProfile === false NO ONE TO SHOW
```

I tried to translate that logic to the angular templates but is not working, i read about templates but maybe is not working with `if elseif elseif else` I don't know how to do that.

```
<ng-container 
*ngIf="allowed && myProfile then restart,reset else if !allowed && myProfile then reset else if allowed && !myProfile then restart else noone ">
</ng-container>


    <ng-template #restart>
    <div clas="col-sm-6">
      RESTART PASSWORD
    </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #reset>
    <div clas="col-sm-6">
      RESET PASSWORD
    </div>
    </ng-template>
```

Maybe this is not the best way to do, I´m open to suggestions

Comment: [Here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ng-template-ng-content-ng-container-and-ngtemplateoutlet-4b7b51223691/) is a great article delves deep into how **ng-content**, **ng-container**, **ng-template** and **ngTemplateOutlet** work. It's worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to do this:

```
<div *ngIf="allowed === true" class="col-sm-6">
      RESTART PASSWORD
</div>

<div *ngIf="myProfile === true" class="col-sm-6">
      RESET PASSWORD
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `ngSwitch` and turn your two fields into an object. Then you could do something like the following.

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="permission">
  <ng-template *ngSwitchCase="permission.profile"></ng-template>
  <ng-template *ngSwitchCase="permission.allowed && permission.profile"></ng-template>
</div>
```

https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

EDIT: The following is a much cleaner solution. This should cater to all your logic. Just add the `ngIf` directives onto the divs you need to show / hide. You should not need to use `ng-templates` for what you are trying to achieve.

```html
<div *ngIf="myProfile">Profile Content</div>

<div *ngIf="allowed">Allowed Content</div>
```